# Malloc/free double free or corruption error

Tags: c, string, initialization, malloc, free

I have a problem with a simple `malloc`/`free` functions I use in a more complex program and I can't find how to get rid of this problem.

My project looks like :

main.c

```
while(1){programm();}
```

I tried a lot of tests to know where it come from but I just can't find a solution...

here is the code part where it seems to bug :

programm.c

```
 void programm(){

     ... Creating variables and getting infos from socket ...
    char a[512];
    char b[512]; 
    sprintf(a,"blablabla",strlen(a)); 
    sprintf(b,"blablabla",strlen(b)); 
    char* MessageOut = NULL;
    MessageOut = (char*)malloc(strlen(a)+strlen(b));
    if(MessageOut==NULL)
        printf("MessageOut Is Null\n");
    else
        printf("%x\n",(uint)MessageOut);

    printf("Size of Malloc:%d\n",strlen(a)+strlen(b));
    sprintf( (char*)MessageOut, "%s%s",a, b );

    MessageOut[0] = 0x02;
    MessageOut[1] = Data[1];
    MessageOut[2] = Data[2];
    MessageOut[3] = 0x03;
    byte_nb = sendto(client_socket, (void *)MessageOut, strlen(a)+strlen(b), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dist_addr, addr_len); 
    if (byte_nb == -1) {
        printf("send error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        printf("%i bytes sent\n", byte_nb);
    }

    printf("%s\n",MessageOut);
    if(MessageOut==NULL)
        printf("MessageOut Is Null\n");
    else
        printf("%x\n",(uint)MessageOut);

    free(MessageOut);
        printf("Test\n");
}
```

As I said it is just a part of my code, I tried to summarize it to the part where it goes wrong.

All of this is in a `while(1)`-loop.

The error I got is double free or corruption (!prev)

The `printf` give me :

```
1c7eeb0
Size Of Malloc : 196
196 Bytes sent
1c7eeb0
```

The first loop works correctly but after a few one I got

```
Error: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x01c7eeb0
```

It does not seems to be a problem with the socket because I have the same address before and after the `sendto`.

Comment: Out of bounds write, undefined behavior.

Comment: So how are `a` and `b` defined and set?

Comment: You should allocate one byte more to store the null terminator.

Comment: yes a and b are defined and set.  char a[512];
 char b[512]; sprintf(a,"blablabla",strlen(a)); sprintf(b,"blablabla",strlen(b)); sorry I should have mentionned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
sprintf(a,"blablabla",strlen(a));
```

`strlen()` is passed an uninitialised `a` which invokes undefined behaviour.

To initially set `a` initialise it on definition:

```
char a[512] = "blablabla";
```

or set it right after:

```
char a[512];
strcpy(a, "blablabla");
```

(The same applies to `b`)

---

Assuming `a` and `b` were set correctly this call

```
sprintf( (char*)MessageOut, "%s%s",a, b );
```

would write 1 `char` beyond `MessageOut` bounds, as after setting the data as per `a` and `b` and additional `'\0'` will be put, the so called `0`-terminator, that every C-"string" carries to maker is end.

To fix this adjust the related call to `malloc()` accordingly:

```
  MessageOut = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1); /* There is no need to cast 
                                                     the result fo malloc in C. */
```